# Scale images up or down?

Tags: ios, image, image-scaling

I apologise if this is obvious, but I'm not too experienced with graphics.

I'm looking at making a game of solitaire for iOS. I understand that the resolution of the iPhone 6s Plus (biggest iPhone) is 414x736, but this is scaled up by x3.

I'm wondering if I should design my images for the 414x736 resolution and have scale them up for the bigger iPhones, or design them for 1242x2208 and scale them down for smaller resolutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter. A scaled down image looks pretty good. A scaled up image looks blocky, and on a higher resolution screen, this will be obvious.

Moreover, if automatic scaling down doesn't look good enough, you can hand-tweak and provide both a `3x` and a `2x` image and the right one will be used automatically depending on the screen resolution of the current device.

Comment: This is not always correct, scaling always has issues. If you have a hairline, it will vanish when scaled down, but scaling up will just blur it.  
You should always use xcasset bundles and provide all resolutions for best user experience (as you wisely stated). This is also required for App Thinning ...

Answer (score 1):

You said "I understand that the resolution of the iPhone 6s Plus (biggest iPhone) is 414x736, but this is scaled up by x3." No, that's incorrect.

The 6 plus has a 1242x2208 pixel screen resolution. However, the native coordinate system is expressed in points (1/72 of an inch.) To get the best looking results you should provide images at the full pixel resolution for your largest device, plus images scaled down to smaller sizes as well. They will all have the same size in inches, but the @3x images will have much more detail to them.